# Is there a shortcut to implement interface methods in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I type something along the line of this:

```
class Foo implements Bar{}
```

intellij idea highlights that line and then I have to hover over it with the mouse pointer until a red lightbulb pops up and click "Implement methods". Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/implementing-methods-of-an-interface.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ctrl+I/Cmd+I (Windows/Mac) is the shortcut for "Implement Methods" in the default IntelliJ keymap.

Comment: This may have been correct 7 years ago but in 2023, there's a ctrl button on Macs and Ctrl+I is what works for IntelliJ by default, not Cmd+I

Answer (score 4):

It also depends on which Keymap you are using. For instance, I am using Jetbrains Rider on MacOS and the shortcut for implementing missing members is "Cmd+Shift+I".

To be able to learn your shortcut key, go to Preferences (Cmd + ',') and select Keymap.  You can just type 'implementation' to the search bar on the right, or Navigate to the Main menu > Code > Implement Methods. You will see the shortcut defined according to your settings.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is no longer correct for Macs; the shortcut is Cmd+I on a standard IntelliJ install now.